# Handling emoji in PHP

Tags: php, ios, twitter, html-email, emoji

I am working on an iOS app, which will send some text which contains **Emojies**.

Ex: Trees in the sun\ud83d\ude0a \ud83d\ude04

The above string sent by iOS App. I am storing this String in Mysql DB.
I am displaying the same string on Web page using Twitter Emoji library

https://blog.twitter.com/2014/open-sourcing-twitter-emoji-for-everyone

But I am not able to send same text/status through html mail content.
Because Gmail won't accept javascript in mails.
Anybody have solution how I can send Emoji through html mail content?

Answer (score 0):

Try this library for server-side translation into HTML: https://github.com/iamcal/php-emoji